# Доступ открывается только по пингу

Tags: linux, ssh, ping

Есть linux система(далее server). К server подключаюсь по SSH (локально).
На сервере что-то настроена таким образом, что я могу подключиться по SSH только после того как делаю ping(на сервере) свой айпишник(машина откуда я подключаюсь к server).
Подскажите пожалуйста, где посмотреть\проверить эти настройки, чтобы убрать доступ по пингу? Что это может быть?
Даже не знаю где смотреть. В iptables, ufw ничего нету... Что писать в гугл тоже не врубаюсь)

Comment: *я могу подключиться по SSH только после того как делаю ping(на сервере) свой айпишник(машина откуда я подключаюсь к server).* Эммм... а для выполнения этого пинга ты как к серверу подключаешься, если SSH недоступен?

Comment: Данное время приходится идти к серверу и делать пинг, потом обратно прийти на свое место:)

Comment: Смотри запущенные systemd службы. Возможно там какой-от кастом висит.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что используется какой-то вариант [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking). Почитайте [там](https://putty.org.ru/articles/port-knocking.html) и [там](https://habr.com/ru/post/673790/).
В целом не вижу проблем, достаточно написать скрипт типа такого

```
$cat sshk
#!/bin/bash
addr=(${1//@/ })
ping -c4 ${addr[0]}
ssh $@
```

И потом вызывать его как `sshk user@host`